# -bash: ≈: command not found (OS X Terminal Error), How to Fix?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, command

Whenever I start up Terminal on my Macbook Air, I get this message:

```
-bash: ≈: command not found
```

How do I fix this error? I'm running Mavericks version 10.9.4 if that helps at all.

EDIT: Fixed this error by using the bash -x method, found out it was a random '≈' character left in ~/.profile that needed to be deleted. Thanks for the answers :)

Comment: You have an erroneous command in one of your startup scripts, like `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`.

Comment: I don't see anything out of the ordinary in either .bash_profile or .bashrc, is there something else that could cause this error?

Comment: Put `set -x` at the top of each script. It will then display each line as it's executing it, you'll then be able to see where the error is happening.

Comment: serach for something like ` =` `space and =`

Comment: Also looked variable assignments that incorrectly start with `$`.  For example, `$JAVA= something` or `$JAVA = something` will generate that error is JAVA if empty/undefined before the assignment.

Comment: looks like your prompt (PS1) may have an invalid character. you can try to isolate this by renaming or commenting out large blocks of your .bash* files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug you can try this:

```
bash -x -l
```

(the `-l` might not be needed).

Comment: agree. to improve a little put `#!/bin/bash -x` as the first line of your .bash* files

Comment: @MikeD I think this is better because then I don't have to modify the .bash* files. I just spawn a new bash session with -x set.

Comment: @MikeD Anyway the correct thing would then be to do 'set -x' as the first line as it is a sourced file, not a script :)

Comment: Fair enough! I suppose you are asking the questioner to source the .bash* files directly from the shell, which would make sense.

Comment: You could even do `bash -x ~/.profile` and `bash -x ~/.bash_profile` and `bash -x ~/.bashrc` to see which of those triggers the problem, without invoking a new login shell which you'd have to exit out of (and without fouling up your current environment).  The only disadvantage is if some variable is currently set that would not be set at login time, in which case more delicate work is required, but the chances are medium to high that this will identify the erroneous line.

Comment: Thank you guys! I figured out it was a random character left in the /.profile that I needed to delete, which fixed the error instantly upon opening a new Terminal afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely agree with Barmar, there is something in your bash startup scripts. 
There is not a great way to do this, but here is the protocol to remedy it.

1. Confirm it is your bash profile by first killing the process with a `control + C` if it is hung. Then do a `source ~/.bash_profile` and see if you get that same error.
2. Backup your bash profile `cp ~/.bash_profile bashprofile.txt`
3. Then comment out part of your bash profile. With text wrangler you can do a `command + slash`.
4. Save, then do a `source ~/.bash_profile` and see if the error still prints.
5. Repeat with different areas of the script until you have isolated the infected region.

Comment: After you backup the bash_profile, you can also open a terminal and type: open -e .bash_profile which will open it in Text Editor where you can comment out the offending lines with a # and then save the file. type: . .bash_profile to update it. [credit to steps 4 & 5 from this article](http://redfinsolutions.com/blog/creating-bashprofile-your-mac)